# Como llenar una barra de progreso mientras ir leyendo texto desde un archivo java

Tags: java

Quisiera que me apoyaran por favor en orientarme en cómo ir llenando una barra de progreso mientras voy leyendo línea por línea desde un archivo de texto, he investigado, buscando que se puede usar *swingworker*, *swing utilities invokelater*, pero no sé cuál usar, además de no saber usarlo, ahorita tengo una implementación sin usar lo anterior, pero no quiere avanzar la barra, se queda en 100% no sé si se está congelando la barra porque no puedo ir actualizando a la par que voy leyendo, Intento leer 1000 líneas, al hacer un calculo, cada 10 lineas, avanzar en 1 la barra, hasta llegar al 100 % les comparto lo que tengo. Muchas gracias

**Esta es la clase de la barra**

```
package com.mx.pruebas.componentes;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class Barra {
    
    private JProgressBar barra;
    private JFrame ventana;
    private Color color = new Color(199,0,57);
    
    public Barra() {
        barra = new JProgressBar();
        ventana = new JFrame();
        barra.setValue(0);
        barra.setMaximum(100);
        barra.setForeground(color);
        barra.setStringPainted(true);
        barra.setIndeterminate(false);
        ventana.add(barra);
        ventana.setTitle("Pruebas");
        ventana.setSize(380, 80);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.setResizable(false);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void llenar(int porcentaje) {
        barra.setValue(porcentaje);
    }

}
```

**Esta es la clase para leer el archivo**

```
package com.mx.pruebas.archivos;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.mx.pruebas.componentes.Barra;

public class Archivo {

    private ArrayList<String> listaUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    private Barra b;
    
    public ArrayList<String> leerDesdeArchivoTexto() {
        Path path = Paths.get("src/recursos/urlsAConsumir.txt");
        int umbral = contadorTotalLineas(path);
        int porcentaje = (umbral / 100);
        int contador = 0, avanzar = 0;
        String cadena = null;
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(path)){
            b = new Barra();
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                cadena = sc.nextLine();
                listaUrl.add(cadena);
                contador++;
                if(contador == porcentaje) {
                    avanzar++;
                    b.llenar(avanzar);
                    contador = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return listaUrl;
    }
    
    public int contadorTotalLineas(Path path) {
        int contador = 0;
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(path)) {
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                sc.nextLine();
                contador++;
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return contador;
    }
    
}
```

**Esta es la clase principal para ejecutar**

```
package com.mx.pruebas.inicio;

import com.mx.pruebas.archivos.Archivo;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Archivo().leerDesdeArchivoTexto();

    }

}
```

Comment: Ya me quedó,  muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el programa avanza más rápido de lo que tus ojos pueden ver el avance de la barra.
Podés probar agregando un `Thread.sleep(200)` en el lazo que lee las líneas:

```
if(contador == porcentaje) {
  avanzar++;
  Thread.sleep(200);
  b.llenar(avanzar);
  contador = 0;
}
```